# Gets error in swift when calling a function that returns string

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var swipeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        swipeLabel.text = "0"
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (ViewController.swipeReceive(sender:)))

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipeReceive(sender:)))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

        let  disPlaynumon = swipeReceive(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) // Error here
        swipeLabel.text = disPlaynumon
    }

    func swipeReceive(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> String
    {
        if(sender.direction == .left)
        {
            var disPlaynum = 0
            disPlaynum = disPlaynum-1
            return String(disPlaynum)
        }

        if(sender.direction == .right)
        {
            var disPlaynum = 0
            disPlaynum = disPlaynum+1
            return String(disPlaynum)
        }
return String("not right or left swiped")
    }
}
```

The error is on the line:

```
let  disPlaynumon = swipeReceive(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
```

The error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Type' to expected argument type 'UISwipeGestureRecognizer'

This program is supposed to let user swipe to the right, then the label display is plus one, when to the left, display is minus 1, but I get error when I call the function swipeReceive trying to get the string that will be displayed on the label.

Comment: It doesn't know what to return when the `sender.direction` is not either left or right. You should also catch to return that case.

Comment: How do I catch to return?

Comment: just add a return String("") after the  last if statement to catch everything else.

Comment: The easiest way is to return a default number, e.g., "0" in case it's neither left nor right.

Comment: I have edited it but the error is still there

Comment: You have to fix the line causing the error, not the function you are trying to call.

Comment: How do I fix that line?

Comment: Why are you calling `swipeReceive`? You should not be calling that yourself.

Comment: And you can't return a value from your `swipeReceive` method. That's not a valid signature for a swipe gesture action method. You need to read the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, you cannot do this. What you are trying is calling this method with UISwipeGestureRecognizer?. The method is expecting object and you are passing the class. The method will be called automatically when you swipe in view. So what you can do is:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var swipeLabel: UILabel!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    swipeLabel.text = "0"
    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (ViewController.swipeReceive(sender:)))

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipeReceive(sender:)))

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right

    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    //REMOVE THESE TWO FROM HERE
   // let  disPlaynumon = swipeReceive(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) // Error here
    //swipeLabel.text = disPlaynumon

}

func swipeReceive(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    var displayNum = 0
    if(sender.direction == .left){
        displayNum = displayNum - 1
    }

    if(sender.direction == .right){
        displayNum = displayNum + 1
    }
    swipeLabel.text = "\(displayNum)"
}


}
```